# How to tell matplotlib to do not consider anything other than numbers from 1 to 1000?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

Noob here. I have this script that plots my data data every 5 minutes from a refreshing .csv file. Problem is that there are sometimes bugs in the .csv data. Maybe letters, maybe some other stuff. How do I tell matplotlib to do not consider anything that is not a number from 1 to 1000? Ill paste my code below. Thanks.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter, DayLocator, 
YearLocator, MinuteLocator
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser
import os
import time
import pylab
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date
os.chdir('/home/pi/csvdata')

time.sleep(30)
def plotloop():
hours = (HourLocator())
minutes = (MinuteLocator())
days = (DayLocator())
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%X %x')      # e.g., 12
for plotinsideloop in range(300000):
    dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) 
        for fn in os.listdir("/home/pi/csvdata") if 
fn.lower().endswith('.csv')]
    dated_files.sort()
    dated_files.reverse()
    newest = dated_files[0][1]
    with open(newest) as f:
        data = list(reader(f))
    humidity = [i[1] for i in data]
    dates1 = [i[0] for i in data]
    dates = [datetime.strptime(i, '%X %x') for i in dates1]
    #print dates
    print dates1[0], dates1[-1]
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFormatter)
    firstdate = (dates[0])
    firstdate1 = str(firstdate)#[:10]
    print "_______"
    #print firstdate
    lastdate = (dates[-1])
    lastdate1 = str(lastdate)
    lastdate2 = lastdate1.replace(" ", " ")
    firstdate2 = firstdate1.replace(" ", " ")
    lastdate3 = lastdate2.replace(":", " ")
    firstdate3 = firstdate2.replace(":", " ")
    lastdate4 = lastdate3.replace("-", " ")
    firstdate4 = firstdate3.replace("-", " ")
    lastdate5 = lastdate4.split(" ")
    firstdate5 = firstdate4.split(" ")
    print lastdate4
    print firstdate4
    firstdate6 = map(int, firstdate5)
    lastdate6 = map(int, lastdate5)
    #lastdate6 = [int(z) for z in lastdate5]
    #firstdate6 = [int(v) for v in firstdate5]
#    firstdatey = int.firstdate4[0]
##        firstdatem
##        firstdated
##        firstdateh
##        firstdatemin
##        firstdatesec

    print lastdate6
    print firstdate6
    titlename = (firstdate1, " - ", lastdate1)
    print titlename
    #print lastdate
    ax.set_xlim(datetime (*firstdate6), datetime (*lastdate6))
    pyplot.ylim(10,50) 
    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    pyplot.setp(pyplot.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, 
horizontalalignment='right')
    pyplot.xticks(rotation=15)
    pyplot.plot_date(dates, humidity)
    pyplot.title(titlename)
    pyplot.savefig(newest + '_2.png', dpi=260)
    pyplot.savefig("plot_2.png", dpi=260)
    #pyplot.savefig("test.pdf")
    print ("Done")
    print(lastdate)
    time.sleep(300)



plotloop()
```

And here goes the updated code which hangs:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter, DayLocator, YearLocator, MinuteLocator
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser
import os
import time
import pylab
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date
os.chdir('/home/pi/csvdata')

#time.sleep(30)
def plotloop():
        hours = (HourLocator())
        minutes = (MinuteLocator())
        days = (DayLocator())
        dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%X %x')      # e.g., 12
        for plotinsideloop in range(300000):
                dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) 
                        for fn in os.listdir("/home/pi/csvdata") if fn.lower().endswith('.csv')]
                dated_files.sort()
                dated_files.reverse()
                newest = dated_files[0][1]
                with open(newest) as f:
                        data = list(reader(f))

        humidity = [i[1] for i in data]
        dates1 = [i[0] for i in data]
        humdates = zip(humidity,dates1)
        humdatesfiltered = []
        for humdate in humdates:
            try:
                if 1 <= humdate[0] <= 1000:
                    humdatesfiltered.append(humdate)
            except TypeError:
                pass 

        dates = [datetime.strptime(i, '%X %x') for i in dates1]
        #print dates
        print dates1[0], dates1[-1]
        fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
        fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFormatter)
        firstdate = dates[0]
        lastdate = dates[-1]
        print "_______"

        titlename = (firstdate1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), " - ", lastdate1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        print titlename

        ax.set_xlim(firstdate1, lastdate1)
        pyplot.ylim(10,50) 
        ax.xaxis_date()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        pyplot.setp(pyplot.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
        pyplot.xticks(rotation=15)
        pyplot.plot_date([i[1] for i in humdatesfiltered], 
                         [i[0] for i in humdatesfiltered])
        pyplot.title(titlename)
        pyplot.savefig(newest + '_2.png', dpi=260)
        pyplot.savefig("plot_2.png", dpi=260)
        #pyplot.savefig("test.pdf")
        print "Done"
        print lastdate
       #       time.sleep(300)




plotloop()
```

Comment: What is this line for `for plotinsideloop in range(300000):`?

Comment: Thats how made it to loop for very long to keep refreshing the plot

Comment: Ok I see. Then you need the code that comes after `data = list(reader(f))` to be indented to the same level as `with open(newest) as f:`

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @GamerDude welcome to SO. Please, next time show some work that you've done yourself to address the problem you're facing, as well as say what other problems you came across. Also, making your code as succinct as possible will make more people take the time to read it, understand the error, and help you.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Hi. Will keep that in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you'd want to remove those problematic values but you can't just remove them from one of the list comprehensions because then your two lists will have a different number of elements.

What you can do is [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together and then remove the offending values. The below will do that even if there are letters in the humidity list.

```
def plotloop():
    hours = (HourLocator())
    minutes = (MinuteLocator())
    days = (DayLocator())
    dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%X %x')      # e.g., 12
    for plotinsideloop in range(300000):
        dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) 
                for fn in os.listdir("/home/pi/csvdata") if fn.lower().endswith('.csv')]
        dated_files.sort()
        dated_files.reverse()
        newest = dated_files[0][1]
        with open(newest) as f:
                data = list(reader(f))

        humidity = [i[1] for i in data]
        dates1 = [i[0] for i in data]
        humdates = zip(humidity,dates1)
        humdatesfiltered = []
        for humdate in humdates:
            try:
                if 1 <= humdate[0] <= 1000:
                    humdatesfiltered.append(humdate)
            except TypeError:
                pass 

        dates = [datetime.strptime(i, '%X %x') for i in dates1]
        #print dates
        print dates1[0], dates1[-1]
        fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
        fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFormatter)
        firstdate = dates[0]
        lastdate = dates[-1]
        print "_______"

        titlename = (firstdate1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), " - ", lastdate1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        print titlename

        ax.set_xlim(firstdate1, lastdate1)
        pyplot.ylim(10,50) 
        ax.xaxis_date()
        ax.autoscale_view()
        pyplot.setp(pyplot.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
        pyplot.xticks(rotation=15)
        pyplot.plot_date([i[1] for i in humdatesfiltered], 
                         [i[0] for i in humdatesfiltered])
        pyplot.title(titlename)
        pyplot.savefig(newest + '_2.png', dpi=260)
        pyplot.savefig("plot_2.png", dpi=260)
        #pyplot.savefig("test.pdf")
        print "Done"
        print lastdate
        #       time.sleep(300)    

plotloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But when I try to run the code i get syntax error on "print titlename". If I comment it out, i get syntax error on the next line "ax.set_xlim(firstdate1, lastdate1)" . I don't get it whats wrong

Comment: @GamerDude: ah there was a missing close paren. Please try now.

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems to have fixed the problem, however now the script just hangs with 100percent cpu usage, not sure what is it calculating but its taking very long. Nothing happening in Shell

Comment: What is the last `print` statement it got to before spinning?

Comment: It doesn't print anything, no action whatsoever in the Shell

Comment: Can you try removing the call to `time.sleep(300)`?

Comment: No change, same situation

Comment: Weird. Would you post into the question the full, current code you're using?

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you for your time

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the code in my answer with the proper indentation. It should work as expected now...

Comment: Again, thanks so much for your time, but now it draws the plot, but it is empty. It looks like puts all the dates but values are not there. Can it be because I have some values like 28.05 ?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why that's occurring let me think about it.

Comment: Thanks dude, the other guy posted his answer and it worked. No idea what is the difference but thanks

Comment: Sure, anytime. Glad you have a working solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a restructured version that might be easier to work with:

```
import csv
import datetime
import glob
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')    # has to be called before pyplot is imported
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter, DayLocator, YearLocator
import os
# import pylab
from time import sleep

CSV_DIR       = "/home/pi/csvdata"
DATE_FORMAT   = "%X %x"         # ex "07:06:05 09/30/13"
DAY_FORMAT    = "%Y-%m-%d"      # ex "2013-09-30"
INITIAL_DELAY = 30
REDRAW_DELAY  = 300

DEBUG = True
if DEBUG:
    def debug_print(s):
        print(s)
else:
    def debug_print(s):
        pass

def wait(i):
    debug_print("Waiting for {} seconds".format(i))
    sleep(i)

def get_newest_file(dir, ext=None):
    debug_print("Finding newest file")
    if ext is None:
        # no ext given - match all file extensions
        filespec = "*"
    elif ext[:1] == ".":
        # ext starts with period - don't repeat it
        filespec = "*" + ext
    else:
        # no period - insert one
        filespec = "*." + ext

    # make full search path
    path = os.path.join(dir, filespec)
    # get all matching files
    file_names = glob.glob(path)

    if not file_names:
        # no matching files found
        debug_print("  nothing found")
        return None
    else:
        # find newest file
        newest = max(file_names, key = os.path.getmtime)
        debug_print("  found {}".format(newest))
        return newest

def get_humidity_data(csv_fname):
    hum = []
    dat = []
    parsetime = datetime.datetime.strptime
    debug_print("Reading data")
    good, skip = 0, 0
    with open(csv_fname, "r") as csv_file:
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            try:
                h = int(row[1])
                d = parsetime(row[0], DATE_FORMAT)
                if 1 <= h <= 1000:
                    hum.append(h)
                    dat.append(d)
                    good += 1
                else:
                    skip += 1
            except ValueError:
                skip += 1
    debug_print("  found {} good rows, skipped {} bad rows".format(good, skip))
    return hum, dat

def make_graph(humidities, dates_):
    firstdate = dates_[0]
    lastdate = dates_[-1]
    graph_title = "{} - {}".format(firstdate.strftime(DAY_FORMAT), lastdate.strftime(DAY_FORMAT))
    debug_print("Making graph for {}".format(graph_title))

    # create new plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.2)
    # configure axes
    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(HourLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(DATE_FORMAT))
    ax.set_xlim(firstdate, lastdate)
    ax.set_ylim(10,50)
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
    plt.xticks(rotation=15)
    # add data
    plt.plot_date(dates_, humidities)
    plt.title(graph_title)
    return fig

def plot_humidity():
    newest = get_newest_file(CSV_DIR, "csv")
    if newest is None:
        debug_print("No data file found!")
    else:
        h, d = get_humidity_data(newest)
        fig = make_graph(h, d)
        fig.savefig(newest + '_2.png', dpi=260)
        # fig.savefig("plot_2.png", dpi=260)
        # pyplot.savefig("test.pdf")
        debug_print("Done")

def main():
    wait(INITIAL_DELAY)
    while True:
        plot_humidity()
        wait(REDRAW_DELAY)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had to change csf to csv and there is no 'bad' defined so I stripped it but it works beautifully. And the code looks beautiful. Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry, fixed two typos.

Comment: One question, i don't quite understand, will it check for new file everytime or only when script is launched?

Comment: `main()` calls `plot_humidity()` every five minutes; each time, `plot_humidity()` finds the newest file, loads the data, and plots it.